# Gitlab : File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, gitlab

I built a Gitlab server that worked perferctly just right before i installed and configured the "git-commit-nottifier" gem.

I edited the Gemfile, to make it work, but after the edit I destroyed the Gitlab web Interface. Now i get the error

```
500 We're sorry, but something went wrong
```

The production logfile says :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable:   bootstrap/variables.
 Load paths:
  Sass::Rails::Importer(/home/git/gitlab/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss)
 /home/git/gitlab/app/assets/stylesheets
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-   0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
 Compass::SpriteImporter
(in /home/git/gitlab/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss)):
  4:     = "#{title} | " if defined?(title)
  5:     GitLab
  6:   = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
  7:   = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
  8:   = javascript_include_tag "application"
  9:   = csrf_meta_tags
  10:   = include_gon
 app/assets/stylesheets/gitlab_bootstrap.scss:8
app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:16
app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml:7:in   `_app_views_layouts__head_html_haml__305352500__582078418'
app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:3:in   `_app_views_layouts_devise_html_haml___761996145__582431808'
```

I red almost every solutions given about this error, but nothing helped...My gemfile now (in the area that the solutions point) is this :

```
group :assets do
gem "sass-rails" 
gem "coffee-rails"
gem "uglifier"
gem "therubyracer"
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'chosen-rails',     "1.0.0"
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'jquery-atwho-rails', "0.3.0"
gem "jquery-rails",     "2.1.3"
gem "jquery-ui-rails",  "2.0.2"
gem "modernizr",        "2.6.2"
gem "raphael-rails",    git: "https://github.com/gitlabhq/raphael-rails.git"
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "gemoji", "~> 1.2.1", require: 'emoji/railtie'
gem "gon"
end
```

I also added "sass-rails" or/and "bootstrap-sass" outside the assets but nothing happened...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: I couldn't find an actual solution for this problem, although I did reinstalled the service while succeeding to keep all the projects and the users, just like it was before. If anyone wants I can post this method.